# How do I install SSL certificates on OS X so I can clone projects from Github?

Tags: macos, ssl, github, git-clone

I am trying to clone a repository at Github, but I am getting SSL Certificate problems.

```
$ git clone  https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments.git  
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Bryan/work/django-threadedcomments/.git/
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing    https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

How do I install the appropriate certificates?

EDIT: I was able to avoid the issue entirely by using git:// versus https://

Comment: It's the strangest thing, I've never had SSL certificate problems with Github and even _that_ clone command seems to work fine (for me). Do you have any proxies in between your machine and the Internet?

Comment: Why do you prefer https over ssh connection?

Comment: I have cloned other projects from Github and never had an issue with SSL. The building where I live may have some type of firewall recently.

Comment: @BryanWheelock, perhaps you were cloning using a `git://` URL (via SSH)?

Comment: @BryanWheelock Just out of curiosity, do you get SSL certificate errors if you go to `https://github.com/` in your browser?

Answer (score 15):

Open *Keychain Access*, select all the certificates in "System Roots" (except those crossed out, if any), right click and export all the items into a PEM file.

Then, use `git config --system http.sslCAInfo /path/to/this/file.pem`. If you don't want to set this globally with `--system` before cloning that particular repository, you can set this path in the `GIT_SSL_CAINFO` environment variable (e.g. `GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/path/to/this/file.pem git clone ...`). This will make Git (and libcurl) use that file as the trusted CA file. (You can check the details for this option in the [git-config man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config).)

Comment: Thank you so much. A shame it appears that OP never tried to take your advice. I'm a bit of a git noob, but I had to use git config --global and not --system